# Is there mention of zoroaster or avesta in any of the puranas?

Tags: vedas, puranas

Zoroaster who started his own religion, language of avesta is similar to Vedas too. Is there mention of him or similar person?

Any such person in bhavishya puran?

Comment: great question.  If it does appear in Sanskrit it must appear as jaratushtra ("with old camels", maybe ) since sanskrit doesn't have 'z'.  This might help date Indo-Aryan in relation to Avestan.

Comment: since mahabharata mentions all kinds of nationalities - thats a possible source

Comment: @SK zoroaster in avesta claims to be an atharvan, coincidentally the preists of atharvaveda are also called atharvan. Atharva Veda was also the last Veda to be compiled, compiled in ending dwapara Yuga to be precise.

Comment: I accept dates in India's past only if confirmed by greek,jain,buddhist, muslim christian etc.sources.  I also accept relative dating based on historical linguistics.  "dwapara yuga" is just fancy.

Comment: @SK that's okay, But we are on a religious site about Hinduism and here most people prefer the timing given by puranas, I never understood why there are so many borderline atheists on this site who write offensive things, this is no linguistic site where one is researching about "indo-iranian" relations.

Comment: I believe Hinduism has no theology - its core is the attainment of nirvikalpa samadhi.  you don't need words, gods, sects etc. for that.